# Change Row and Column Position

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have a Windows Univeral app. 
I have a grid with two column, inside the two column it has a textbox and button. I want to change the Grid's column and row based on the screen size.
When the screen size is more than 1000, the grid will have one row with two column. Or the grid will have two row, one column.

Comment: You can use converter for this. First define two rows and two columns. Assign the row and column using converter. Converter will return row and column number depending on screen size. Let me know if you any problem

Comment: You should probably use RelativePanel for this, and not a Grid. Here's a good intro: http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/04/building-adaptive-layout-in-windows-10-with-relativepanel-and-adaptivetrigger/

Answer (score 1):

Use AdaptiveTrigger to change the Grid.Row or Grid.Column of the child elements.

```
       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=1000 effective pixels -->
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1000" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="myButton.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="myButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="1" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=0 and <1000 effective pixels -->
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="myButton.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="myButton.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Text="TextBox content" Width="200" Height="20" />
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="MyButton" Width="200"  />

    </Grid>
```